# How to convert a javascript object into an NSDictionary using JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, objective-c, javascriptcore

Let's say I have a javascript file, `javascript.js`, with the following content.

```
window.fruitsAndVeggies = {
    name2CategoryMap: {
        "apple": "fruit",
        "carrot": "vegetable"
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me the easiest way to get the contents of the Javascript object `window.fruitsAndVeggies` into an NSDictionary?

From various sources on the internet I've pieced together the following snippet, that creates a Javascript context, and then evaluates the javascript code in that context.

```
JSGlobalContextRef ctx = JSGlobalContextCreate(NULL);  // create context


JSValueRef exception = JSValueMakeUndefined(ctx); // create object to hold exceptions

// Make a "window" object in the JS Context
JSStringRef makeWindowScript = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("var window = {}");
JSValueRef result = JSEvaluateScript( ctx, makeWindowScript, NULL, NULL, 0, &exception );


// load the javascript file into an NSString
NSBundle *          bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"my.bundle"];
NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"javascript" ofType:@"js"];

NSError *error;
NSString *stringFromFile = [[NSString alloc]
                                 initWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                 error:&error];

// convert NSString to a JSStringRef
CFStringRef cfString = (__bridge CFStringRef)stringFromFile;
JSStringRef jsString = JSStringCreateWithCFString(cfString);


// evaluate the javascript
JSEvaluateScript( ctx, jsString, NULL, NULL, 0, &exception );
```

I'm confused as to what to do next. I need to use the contents of `fruitsAndVeggies.name2CategoryMap` in my objective-c code. What's the easiest way to access them?  Is there a simple function I can call to load them into an objective-c dictionary?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things have become a lot simpler since the new Objective-C interface in JavaScriptCore introduced with iOS 7.  For an intro to this, see the WWDC 2013 session "Integrating JavaScript into Native Apps" session on Apple's developer network: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=615

The code you need after evaluating the javascript resource file is:

```
    JSContext *context = [JSContext contextWithJSGlobalContextRef:ctx];
    NSDictionary *fruitsAndVeggiesDict = [context[@"window"][@"fruitsAndVeggies"][@"name2CategoryMap"] toObject];

    NSLog(@"name2CategoryMap['apple'] = %@", fruitsAndVeggiesDict[@"apple"]);
    NSLog(@"name2CategoryMap['carrot'] = %@", fruitsAndVeggiesDict[@"carrot"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as I might, I couldn't figure out an elegant way to get `window.fruitsAndVeggies` into a dictionary. The best I could do was to hand-roll a loop that iterates through the javascript object and adds each key/value pair to a dictionary one-by-one.

The code's below. Be warned: it's ugly. If you've got a more succinct solution, I'm all ears!

```
/* Make the dictionary. */
NSMutableDictionary *fruitsAndVeggiesDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


/* In the JS context, create a variable called "keys". 
   Return the number of keys (keys.length).  */
result = JSEvaluateScript( ctx, JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("var keys = Object.keys(window.fruitsAndVeggies.name2CategoryMap); keys.length"), NULL, NULL, 0, &exception );

double numKeys = JSValueToNumber(ctx, result, &exception);


/* Iterate over the keys; convert each key/value into a pair of NSStrings. */
for(int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++){

    // get a key, save in keyStrNS
    NSString *getKeyStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"keys[%d]", i];
    CFStringRef getKeyStrCF = (__bridge CFStringRef)getKeyStr;
    JSStringRef getKeyStrJS = JSStringCreateWithCFString(getKeyStrCF);

    JSValueRef key = JSEvaluateScript( ctx, getKeyStrJS, NULL, NULL, 0, &exception );

    JSStringRef keyStrJS = JSValueToStringCopy(ctx, key, &exception);
    NSString *keyStrNS = (NSString *)JSStringCopyCFString( kCFAllocatorDefault, keyStrJS );


    // get a value, save in valueStrNS
    NSString *getValueStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.fruitsAndVeggies.name2CategoryMap[\"%@\"]", keyStrNS];
    CFStringRef getValueStrCF = (__bridge CFStringRef)getValueStr;
    JSStringRef getValueStrJS = JSStringCreateWithCFString(getValueStrCF);

    JSValueRef value = JSEvaluateScript( ctx, getValueStrJS, NULL, NULL, 0, &exception );

    JSStringRef valueStrJS = JSValueToStringCopy(ctx, value, &exception);
    NSString *valueStrNS = (NSString *)JSStringCopyCFString( kCFAllocatorDefault, valueStrJS );

    /* store the key and value in our dictionary */
    [fruitsAndVeggiesDict setObject: valueStrNS  forKey: keyStrNS];

    /* and print them for good measure */
    NSLog(@"key %@ has value %@",keyStrNS,valueStrNS);

}
```

Output:

```
key apple has value fruit
key carrot has value vegetable
```